# jquery loading when load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have script like this

```
function manualSeat(){
    $('.dimmed').show();
    $("#petaKursi").load('url');
    $('#wagonCode').val('');
    $('#wagonNumber').val('');
    $('#selSeats').val('');
    selectedGerbong = '';
    selectedSeats = Array();
    $('#manualSeatMap').show();
    $('.dimmed').hide(); 
}
```

that code above doesn't work maybe because code doesn't wait until load syntax finish loading,..(maybe)

what i want to ask is,how to make `my $('.dimmed')`
works like loading that start when begin(show) loading and stop when loading finish(hide)

what i want is like this::
page load(with every div)=>click a button=>load a page to div(when loading,showLoader),when finish loading (hideLoader)

Comment: You must have a loader element in DOM which will have some gif or css3 loader and initialled its css display property will be set to **block**, once you know that **window.onload** event is triggered, hide the loader element..

Comment: Tyre to load the JQuery Lib first `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` then try your request in script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Rayon Dabre
what i actually want is like this

```
function manualSeat(){
    dimmed.fadeIn();
    $("#petaKursi").load('blablabla', function() {
       dimmed.fadeOut();
        });
    $('#wagonCode').val('');
    $('#wagonNumber').val('');
    $('#selSeats').val('');
    selectedGerbong = '';
    selectedSeats = Array();
    $('#manualSeatMap').fadeIn(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var dimmed = $('.dimmed');
var showLoader = function () {
    dimmed.fadeIn();
};
var hideLoader = function () {
    dimmed.fadeOut();
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showLoader);
window.onload = hideLoader;
```

> You can call showLoader and hideLoader methods whenever you want to show or hide the loader element.

Comment: so close sir, but what i want is like this
loading appear when whole page is loading, not the "$("#petaKursi").load('url');"
page load(with every div)=>click a button=>load a page to div(when loading,showLoader),when finish loading (hideLoader)

Comment: Are you trying to load external URL in DOM ?

Comment: yes sir, i did modified your script, and it works fine now,..
thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to use AjaxStart and AjaxStop function. This way you will fire when the Ajax call (.load is one of them) it will perform some actions.

So in your case:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (){
    //I begin the ajax call so I show the layer
    $('.dimmed').show();
    //you can also do other stuffs like changing the tab title
    document.title = 'loading...';
}).ajaxStop(function (){
    //The ajax loading has ended
    $('.dimmed').hide();
    document.title = 'page';
});
```

I'd go for an ID for the layer that you use while loading to identify it.
If you want to fire this event only for some ajax call and not for other add the

```
global: false
```

attribute to that specific ajax call.